# Session to Handle Direct URL Access in PHP Fail

Tags: php

I created a session to restrict users from accessing the home page via URL and to direct them to the login page(index.php). But users can't log in with correct credentials and it still directs back to the login page. It seems there's an issue with the session as login works without the session.

index.php (root folfer)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="The Best Restaurant..">
  
  <title>Signature Cuisine</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mediaquaries.css">
  
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5cab703b53.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</head> 
<body>  

<div class="page_title_background" id="login_page_background">
    <div class="container" id="login_page_form">
    <form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
     <h2>LOGIN</h2>
     <div class="login_form">
        <label>User Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="uid" autocomplete="off">
     </div>
     <div class="login_form">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="lname" name="pwd" autocomplete="off">
     </div> 
     <div class="adminpage_submitbtn">
     <button name="login" type="submit" id="login_page_submit_btn">Login</button>
     </div>
         <div class="error-message">
            <?php
            $errorMessage = '';
            
            if (isset($_GET["error"])) {
                if ($_GET["error"] == "emptyinput") {
                    $errorMessage = 'Fill in all fields!';
                } elseif ($_GET["error"] == "wronglogin") {
                    $errorMessage = 'Invalid details!';
                } elseif ($_GET["error"] == "stmtfailed") {
                    $errorMessage = 'Something went wrong!';
                } elseif ($_GET["error"] == "none") {
                    $errorMessage = 'Account created!';
                } elseif ($_GET["error"] == "nouser") {
                    $errorMessage = 'User not found!';
                }
            } elseif (isset($_SESSION['error']) && $_SESSION['error'] == 'emptyinput') {
                $errorMessage = 'Fill in all fields!';
            }
            
            echo '<div class="error">' . $errorMessage . '</div>';
            ?>
        </div>
    </form>
 </div>

  <p class="reg_link_p">New Here? <a href="signup.php">Register!</a></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

home.php (root folder)

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!defined('MY_APP')) {
    // If MY_APP is not defined, redirect to another page or display an error message
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}

// Include necessary files such as header
include_once 'header.php';
?>

<!---------------------------------------- PAGE 1 ------------------------------>




<!---------------------------------------- TEST ------------------------------------------>

<?php 
include_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

login.inc.php (root/includes)

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'dbh.inc.php';
require_once 'functions.inc.php';

if (isset($_POST["login"])) {
    $username = $_POST["uid"];
    $pwd = $_POST["pwd"];

    if (emptyInputLogin($username, $pwd)) {
        header('Location:../index.php?error=emptyinput');
        exit();
    }

    $loginResult = loginUser($conn, $username, $pwd);

    if ($loginResult === "success") {
        header('Location: ../home.php');
        exit();
    } elseif ($loginResult === "nouser") {
        header('Location: ../index.php?error=nouser');
        exit();
    } elseif ($loginResult === "wrongpassword") {
        header('Location: ../index.php?error=wronglogin');
        exit();
    }
} else {
    header('Location:../index.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

functions.inc.php (root/includes)

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once 'dbh.inc.php';

function emptyInputSignup($name, $email, $username, $pwd, $pwdRepeat) {
    $result;
    if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($username) || empty($pwd) || empty($pwdRepeat) ) {
        $result = true;
    } else {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}

function invalidUid($username) {
    $result;
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
        $result = true;
    } else {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}

function invalidEmail($email) {
    $result;
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $result = true;
    } else {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}

function pwdMathch($pwd , $pwdRepeat) {
    $result;
    if ($pwd !== $pwdRepeat) {
        $result = true;
    } else {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}

function uidExists($conn, $username) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ad_users WHERE usersUid = ? OR usersEmail = ?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("Location:../index.php?error=stmtfailed");
        exit();
    }
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $resultData = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData)) {
        return $row;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}


function createUser($conn, $name, $email, $username, $pwd) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ad_users (usersName, usersEmail, usersUid, usersPwd) VALUES (?,?,?,?);";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("Location:../signup.php?error=stmtfailed");
        exit();
    }
    $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $name, $email, $username, $hashedPwd);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    header("Location:../index.php?error=none");
    exit();
}

function emptyInputLogin($username, $pwd) {
    if (empty($username) || empty($pwd)) {
        return true; // Return true if input is empty
    }
    return false; // If not empty, return false
}

function loginUser($conn, $username, $pwd) {
    $user = uidExists($conn, $username);

    if ($user === false) {
        // User doesn't exist
        return "nouser";
    }

    $pwdHashed = $user["usersPwd"];
    $checkPwd = password_verify($pwd, $pwdHashed);

    if ($checkPwd === false) {
        // Incorrect password
        return "wrongpassword";
    } else {
        // Password is correct, set session variables and return success
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["userid"] = $user["usersId"];
        $_SESSION["useruid"] = $user["usersUid"];
        $_SESSION["username"] = $user["usersName"];
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Tried different methods to debug and find the issue but failed.
I want the users to login only via index.php to home.php and restrict users using urls to access home page.

Answer (score 0):

On your home page you will need to check if the session is set.

```
if (isset($_SESSION["userid"])){
   header('Location: ../index.php?error=wronglogin');
   exit();
}
```